# LMO without using partner portal

Tags: lmo

I want to create License Management Org (LMO). Can I do it without having Parnter Portal? Can I make any dev org as LMO?

Answer (score 8):

You can't use LMA/LMO without being part of the Salesforce Partner Program.

Be aware that the *Salesforce Partner Portal* (the one for ISV/consulting partners of Salesforce) is not the same thing as Salesforce's *Partner Portal* (the app that customers of Salesforce can use to manage their own partners, and which they must pay a license fee for).

The partner portal you need access to to get LMA/LMO is also known as [Partnerforce](https://sites.secure.force.com/partners/PP2PartnerLoginPage), the name I prefer since it avoids this confusion. You get access to this once you sign up as a Salesforce partner. You must have access to it to get LMA because the very first step in installing LMA is to file a Partner case via Partnerforce.

Salesforce tells you not to make a dev org an LMO if it's being used for developing a managed package, but outside of that I'm not aware of other dev org restrictions. I would strongly recommend against using a dev org for your LMO - IMO your LMO should be the same org you manage your sales/customer service from, and there are many reasons that should not be a dev org. If you're a Salesforce partner you'll get a full CRM org for free, which you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can download the LMA without being part of partner program but that's useless for reasons cited by @jkraybill so don't do that until SF tells you to.

Comment: You mean like if you acquired the installation URL from another ISV without filing a Partnerforce case first? That would be a really bad idea for several reasons.

Comment: The application used to be on the AppExchange, Partnerforce case wasn't needed, however it looks like it's since been removed by SalesForce.